# Merge same name sheets from various excels into one

Tags: excel, python-3.x

I am trying to merge sheets in multiple excels that have the same name into one excel sheet

Have tried the code below:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

files = os.listdir("XXXX")

print("All files in the given directory are :", files)

files_xlsx = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']

print("Excel files in this directory are :", files_xlsx)

y = "XXXX"

excels = [pd.ExcelFile(y +'\\'+ name) for name in files_xlsx]

for each in excels:
    sheets =pd.ExcelFile(each).sheet_names

print ("Sheet names in these excel files are : ", sheets)

NSheets = len(sheets)

print ("Number of different Sheet names in these excel files are : ", NSheets)

for z in sheets:
        frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[i], header=None,index_col=None) for x in excels]
        frames[1:] = [df[1:] for df in frames[1:]]
        combined = pd.concat(frames)
        combined.to_excel("XXXX\\Output_" + z + ".xlsx", header=False, index=False)
```

This results in multiple files created with different sheet names but all those sheets have the same data as in sheet 1. The data is not coming right.

Comment: in your `frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[i], header=None,index_col=None) for x in excels]`, where do you set you `i` variable?

Comment: @prebsus sorry. that was something I was trying. Its actually ` frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None,index_col=None) for x in excels] `

and I know this will return the first sheet always. But I dont know how to create a search based on sheet names so that same sheet names of all excel files combine only

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. I've tried to include what you were looking for here (matching by `sheet name` instead of by `sheet position`) in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I fully understand your question, but I read it as you want 1 Output Excel-file per unique Excel-sheet name input. If so, then try this:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

files = os.listdir("XXXX")

print("All files in the given directory are :", files)

files_xlsx = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']

print("Excel files in this directory are :", files_xlsx)

y = "XXXX"

excels = [pd.ExcelFile(y +'\\'+ name) for name in files_xlsx]

for each in excels:
    sheets =pd.ExcelFile(each).sheet_names


print ("Sheet names in these excel files are : ", sheets)

NSheets = len(sheets)

print ("Number of different Sheet names in these excel files are : ", NSheets)

for z in sheets:
    frames = list()
    for x in excels:
        try:
            x.sheet_names.index(z)
            frames.append(x.parse(x.sheet_names.index(z), header=None, index_col=None))
            frames[1:] = [df[1:] for df in frames[1:]]  # keep only header from first file for each sheetname
            combined = pd.concat(frames)
            combined.to_excel("XXXX\\Output_" + z + ".xlsx", header=False, index=False)
        except:
          pass
```

If I've understood your question correctly then this should do what you want.

PS: I added back the line previously taken out (keeping only the first header) and it seems to do as desired for my small testing sample

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for answering. I have only started learning python since a month, so it was little difficult for me to understand how to work around this issue, but thanks to you, my problem is almost solved. However, I am still facing one issue.

My dataset is such that the first row is headers in each sheet and then I have data in the subsequent rows. Also, the headers are consistent for the sheets with the same name. So my requirement is to have only one header row and then data from subsequent sheets to be appened to the same sheet, without row 1 of headers from them

Comment: When using the code given by you, when these sheets are combined,the header row  (i.e. row 1) is getting generated everytime a new sheet is added

I used this line to get rid of the header i.e. first row for all sheets except the first one ---> 
frames[1:] = [df[1:] for df in frames[1:]]

i.e. it was to keep the header line i.e. row 1 for one sheet from the 1st workbook only and remove the header line i.e. row 1 for all the other sheets that are getting appended.

However, it is not working properly. For my second sheet, 2 rows are getting appended and I am unsure why

Comment: Hi @prebsus , thanks for answering, but the line of code that you have added back has an issue in the no of data rows. If for example, I have 4 workbooks with same sheet name and each with 10 data rows excluding the header, then in the output workbook, the sheet contains total 38 data rows i.e. the header column, plus 10 data rows from first workbook, plus 8 rows from second, plus 9 data rows from the third and 10 data rows from the fourth workbook

Comment: I'm not getting the same results at you, but I'll have a look at this later.